# UI Based Query Builder using jQuery

Tags: jquery, builder

UPDATED!!

Breaking down the question as suggested.

1. I need to create a Look & Feel for a search application
2. I need to have the components displayed on the left hand side and on the right I can drag-and-drop them and enter the data for the search criteria
3. If there are more than one condition I would like to drag and drop the condition
4. Finally I need to save/edit/open existing query

---

I am looking to build a query builder with drag and drop facility to build the query. I was wondering if there are any pointers for this.

I have looked into the jQuery plugins and some examples, but nothing to what I am looking for. Any suggesting?

Comment: Try and break your question down a bit more, what exactly are you struggling with? If it's everything the this will probably get closed as too localized very soon.

Comment: Funny, I think I'm going to have to build something quite similar at work here in a few days.

Comment: @Wouter: May be I can help you with that when you are at the point of implementation, because I have stared to work on it. It would take me sometime to get it up and running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you fail to find something that will work completely how you want. You could try using this idea as a base and coding it up yourself:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/SqlWhereBuilder.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Guess this is not very useful, but I'd guess you have to code something like that yourself. I've been using jQuery for a long time now, and I've never seen any plugins like that. Ever.

Comment: Well looks like you are right, that's gonna take me a while, thought I have an idea about how to go about it, was just wondering in this forum if someone might have come across something atleast close to it.

Answer (score 1):

Its late to reply , but in case somebody come on this page below is the correct solution on jquery. 
http://querybuilder.js.org/

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution for this problem as a drag and drop application
[DND-Query-Builder](https://github.com/MsAlEhR/DND-Query-Builder)

Comment: please can you add context around the link, in case it ever breaks? thank you :)