# Hibernate multi-table query handling

Tags: hibernate

I have 4 tables

1. Titles having the following fields, id (PK), Name, AuthorId(FK) & PublishedId(FK)
2. Author having id(FK), Author Name & Contact Details
3. Publisher having, id(PK), Publisher Name & RegionId(FK)
4. Region having, id(PK), Region Name, Published Date & Published Cost.

Now in my View, I am accepting

1. Author Name, and my code looks like

   SearchTemplate _tempTemplate = new SearchTemplate();
        Criterion criterion = null;

   ```
       if (rcValue.getOperator().equalsIgnoreCase("like")) {
                       criterion = Restrictions.like(rcValue.getDisplayName(), rcValue.getOperandValue());
                   } else if (rcValue.getOperator().equalsIgnoreCase("is")) {
                       criterion = Restrictions.eq(rcValue.getDisplayName(), rcValue.getOperandValue());
                   } else if (rcValue.getOperator().equalsIgnoreCase("not")) {
                       criterion = Restrictions.ne(rcValue.getDisplayName(), rcValue.getOperandValue());
                   }

   _tempTemplate.addCriterion(criterion);
   ```

When I search for Name, I get the right results, but when I search for my Author Name, what do I need to change in my above code?

2.When I search of Published Date, what do I need to change, because its a multi-table search, if its SQL I can easily write it, but using Hibernate now and with an implementation of 'SearchTemplate'

```
/*The SearchTemplate is used to pass search parameters to the DAO layer.
 *
 * By having all the search parameters in one place (the SearchTemplate), 
 * we prevents combinatory explosion of 'find' method signatures in the DAO/Service layer.
 * This leads to more stable DAO/Service interfaces as you can add search parameters to the
 * SearchTemplate without adding new methods to your interfaces.
 *
 * A SearchTemplate helps you drive your search in the following areas:
*/
```

Can someone help with this?

Comment: I don't see any mention of objects in your model, only tables.  Why aren't you creating objects with relationships and mapping those to tables?

Comment: How would I do that? I have no clue on how to work on it, its my 1st time :)

Comment: duffymo is right, you don't usually work with 'tables' with JPA/Hibernate, you work with mapped objects.   So, without mappings your question is incomplete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First question:

You need to make a join (assuming the root entity is title):

```
criteria.createAlias("author", "author");
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("author.name", authorName);
```

Second question:

same answer: you need to make joins:

```
criteria.createAlias("publisher", "publisher");
criteria.createAlias("publisher.region", "region");
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("region.publishedDate", someDate));
```

This SearchTemplate is a really bad idea, IMO. Instead of having well-defined methods with a clear contract like :

```
List<Title> findTitlesWithName(String name)
List<Title> findTitlesPublishedBy(Long publisherId)
Title findLatestTitleFromAuthor(String authorId)
```

You'll have a single method

```
List<Title> findTitles(SearchTemplate criteria)
```

What must you put in the criteria? What's the type of the criteria? What will the method do with these criteria? Which ordering will be applied? Which related entities will be fetched or lazily loaded?

An "explosion" of find methods is a good thing, because each find method has its own contract, optimizations, and goal. Each can also be unit-tested. That's the goal of a DAO. Without these methods, you might as well have a unique method such as

```
List find(String hql, Object[] arguments)
```

But I fail to see the goal of such a DAO.

Comment: The idea being, I would be searching for multiple titles, with/without author names during a published period, so I will have a complex query, but when I initially wrote it, I didn't think much on how the relationships would be maintained, coming from a background of writing SQL more then using HQL/Criteria's, and was asked to learn and implement it in a extremely short span of time, so trying to do my best. I might be implementing it differently, so am trying to learn the right way to do it.

Comment: You can look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7306413/ui-based-query-builder-using-jquery, will give you an idea of what I was trying to do.

Comment: Now I am getting an error Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException occurred calling getter of com.enquiries.domain.Author.id, any ideas on how to work around this?

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate is an ORM technology: object/relational mapping.  I see relational tables in your question, but no mention of objects.

I see at least five objects in your model, maybe more:

1. Title
2. Author
3. Publisher
4. Region
5. ContactDetails

Think about the one-to-many and many-to-many relationships between these objects.  For example, an author might write several titles; a title might have several authors.  Sounds like a reciprocal many-to-many relationship to me.

So the objects might look like this:

```
public class Author {
    private List<Title> titles;  // parent
}

public class Title {
    private List<Author> authors; // child
}
```

Map those as 1:m relationships in Hibernate and it'll help generate the SQL for you.  You won't need HQL nearly as much as you seem to think you do.

Another way to do that many-to-many relationship is to "reify" it into a separate object.  Your design choice, depending on what works better.  That's a good idea if you have attributes that are best kept separate.  An example might be Student and Course (Student takes many Courses; a Course is taken by many Students).  It might make sense to reify this into a ReportCard, that has a Grade, or some other kind of object.

Comment: This is almost what I have right now, thanks for the explanation.